# Exploding array and adding execution timestamp for each bit of data in the array?

Tags: php, curl, curl-multi

Using curl_multi, I have loaded up 3 url's and then printed the array.

1) How can I also set a timestamp on output to let me know when each url was run?

2) How can I explode the array to only display the data and timestamp, excluding the text "Array ( [0] =>", "[1] =>", "[2] =>" and " )"?

**Code**

```
<?php

function multiRequest($data, $options = array()) {

  // array of curl handles
  $curly = array();
  // data to be returned
  $result = array();

  // multi handle
  $mh = curl_multi_init();

  // loop through $data and create curl handles
  // then add them to the multi-handle
  foreach ($data as $id => $d) {

    $curly[$id] = curl_init();

    $url = (is_array($d) && !empty($d['url'])) ? $d['url'] : $d;
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_URL,            $url);
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_HEADER,         0);
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    // post?
    if (is_array($d)) {
      if (!empty($d['post'])) {
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_POST,       1);
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $d['post']);
      }
    }

    // extra options?
    if (!empty($options)) {
      curl_setopt_array($curly[$id], $options);
    }

    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $curly[$id]);
  }

  // execute the handles
  $running = null;
  do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
  } while($running > 0);

  // get content and remove handles
  foreach($curly as $id => $c) {
    $result[$id] = curl_multi_getcontent($c);
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $c);
  }

  // all done
  curl_multi_close($mh);

  return $result;
}



$data = array(array(),array());

$data[0]['url']  = 'http://search.yahooapis.com/VideoSearchService/V1/videoSearch?appid=YahooDemo&query=Pearl+Jam&output=json';
$data[1]['url']  = 'http://search.yahooapis.com/VideoSearchService/V1/videoSearch?appid=YahooDemo&query=Black+Eyed+Peas&output=json';
$data[2]['url']  = 'http://search.yahooapis.com/VideoSearchService/V1/videoSearch?appid=YahooDemo&query=Nirvana&output=json';

$r = multiRequest($data);

print_r($r);

?>
```

**Output**

```
Array ( [0] => Pearl Jam <br>
        [1] => Black Eyed Peas<br>
        [2] => Nirvana )
```

**Preferred Output**

```
01:00:01 Pearl Jam <br>
01:00:02 Black Eyed Peas<br>
01:00:03 Nirvana
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say keep it simple...just do a loop where you set the timestamp and do a single curl call, then explode the resultarray and filter out all key or values you don't need.

For the curl call:

```
$r= array();

foreach($urls as $url) {
 $r[]["timestamp"]= time();
 $output= curl_exec($url);
 $r[]["bandname"]= $output;
}
```

Your final loop would be something like

```
foreach($r as $key=>$value){
 print $value["timestamp"];
 print $value["bandname"];
 print "<br>";
}
```

Comment: So instead of print_r($r); I'd place foreach($r as $key=>$value){... where do i place the first chunk of code? thanks!

Comment: Still confused as to where to place the first "foreach".. It calls curl_exec but I already have a multi_curl in place?

Comment: The curl_exec is a replacement of the multi_curl...I believe it's the only way of setting timestamps with each curl call. THe curl_exec should be placed somewhere near the end of your foreach ($data as $id => $d) loop.. Hope that clears things up a bit.